# Getting the value of a js object key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to get the value of an object key. When I `console.log(event);` a returned object, I am getting:

```
MessageEvent {
    ports: Array[0], 
    data: "{
        "event":"playProgress",
        "data":{
            "seconds":0.419,
            "percent":0.002,
            "duration":177.813
        }
    }"
}
```

I can't seem to get to value of the data.percent with `console.log(event.data.percent)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: console.log(event.data.data.percent) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `event.data` is actually a string, and not a nested object.  With a "reasonably modern" browser, you can:

```
var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
console.log(data.percent);
```

More discussion on `JSON.parse` can be seen at this previous stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686237/3108853).

Comment: Thanks! I got confused over the data in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around your first data object

```
MessageEvent {
    ports: Array[0], 
    data: {
        "event":"playProgress",
        "data":{
            "seconds":0.419,
            "percent":0.002,
            "duration":177.813
        }
    }
}
```

By leaving them in your creating a string rather then an obj

Answer (score 0):

You need to go down another level in your **MessageEvent object** to access the subobject data of the first data object.
In order to console.log you don't even need to stringify and then parse the object, like in this case.

Try below:

```
var MessageEvent = {
    ports: Array[0], 
    data: {
        "event":"playProgress",
        "data":{
            "seconds":0.419,
            "percent":2.002,
            "duration":177.813
        }
    }
};
```

console.log(**MessageEvent.data.data.percent**);

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/em3afkov/